# Uniform Boundedness hypothesis

Tags: functional-analysis

The hypothesis includes stating that the linear operators T, from X to Y, in the family of operators are bounded; how is the statement that follows in the hypothesis any different?

"
 If for all x in X one has

${\displaystyle \sup \nolimits _{T\in F}\|T(x)\|_{Y}<\infty }$, ... "

It seems to me, each $T$ bounded means $\|T(x)\| \leq C\|x\| \leq \infty$, for all $x$, and EACH $T$ including taking 'sup'. What am I missing?

Comment: In the statement we should have that $\sup_{T \in F} \| T\| < \infty$, which is stronger. (And hence shows why it is called the **uniform** boundedness principle!)

Comment: You can have a bound for each $T\in F$ but fail to have a supremum for the set of bounds.

Comment: Nigel: I realize that's the end result. Justin: that comment does make more sense. So is this simply a matter of, for example, if we had a finite set of bounded T's, we could just take the max among these bounds as the uniform bound; but because we're dealing with a possibly infinite sequence, the sup of the bounds may be infinite; yes?